# Reactjs isomorphic-fetch PATCH how to have the body error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xmlhttprequest

So basically I am sending data with a fetch POST or PATCH method and when I have an error I can see in the network -> response this error:

```
{
  "Errors": [
   {
     "Code": -201,
     "Message": "Could not get file from link",
     "AssociatedError": "404 Not Found"
   }
 ],
 "Result": null
}
```

Here is my actual code:

```
function checkStatus(response) {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    return response;
  } else {
    var error = new Error(response.statusText);
    error.response = response;
    throw error;
  }
}

export function sendImageUploaded(data, valueMethod, endpoint) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(requestPosts(data));
        return fetch(endpoint, {
            method: valueMethod,
            headers: new Headers({
                            Authorization: Isengard.config.token
                        }),
            body: data
        })
        .then(checkStatus)
        .then(reponse => {
            dispatch(successSent("The output list has been successfully sent!"));
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log('request failed', err);
            dispatch(failSent("Error on sending request: " + err));
        });
    };
};
```

And I am struggling on having this error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already got your response error in "error.response". You only have to resolve that promise.

instead of

```
.catch(err => {
                console.log('request failed', err);
                dispatch(failSent("Error on sending request: " + err));
});
```

use

```
.catch(err => {
        err.response.json().then((json) =>{
           let {Errors,Result} = json;
           dispatch(failSent(Errors)); // You are sending your array of errors here
        });
});
```